# Audio working on Computers but not on Mobile with JS. Any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, json, audio, mobile

I am working on a musical project with just JS and JSON, the audio works perfect on computers, however on mobile devices the audio doesn't activate. I use some sliders in order to change some parameters such as gain and even though the values DO change, the audio doesn't activate. I use the pointerdown and  pointerup event. Do you have any suggestion about this problem?

I have tried with mouse and clicks events, however pointer events are designed to work on both.

Comment: Please share some code that we can reproduce

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Autoplay policy comes to mind, desktops only require first-time interaction for most part to auto-play audio but mobiles require additional prompting for auto-playback.

Comment: @al366io, @BGPHiJack this is the beginning of the code until now.                                                                                    `async function setup() {
    const patchExportURL = "export/patch.export.json";

    // Create AudioContext
    const WAContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    const context = new WAContext();

    // Create gain node and connect it to audio output
    const outputNode = context.createGain();
    outputNode.connect(context.destination);`